How do I return a list of letters when I input integers into a stack in a python?
I am currently learning python and I am struggling to complete the following task I need to input integers into a stack and convert these to capital letters. I have tried a few variations of the code below but so far the closest I have come to is getting the letter A by itself and I need the full alphabet. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Here is the code so far:
stack = chr(1)
size = len(stack)
top = -1

def push(x):
  global top
  if top >= size - 1: print("Stack Overflow")
  else:
    top = top + 1
    stack[top] = x

def pop():
  global top
  if top == -1: print("Stack Underflow")
  else:
    old_value = stack[top]
    top = top - 1
    stack[top + 1] = 0
    return old_value

print(stack)


not sure what you are trying to do but here s a couple of hints:

chr(97) will give you the letter 'a' (lower case)
chr(97).upper() will give you the upper letter

then if you need the xth character you can do chr(97+x).upper() for any x in [0:25].
(Alternatively you can do chf(96+x).upper() for x in [1:26])
